# Use Milliseconds on Time Manager

Tags: qgis, excel, time, timemanager

I am trying to use Timemanager with my csv files which i loaded on my map as shp layer. those contain time staps which i tried in hh:mm:ss.fff hh:mm:ss:fff hh:mm:ss,fff and also each with 1 f - in the exvel csv and in timemanager and layer properties.
Time is running but layers arent displayed.
I then loaded the data without milliseconds hh:mm:ss and it was working after i formated the excel table to that time stamp.

However, i still cant get milliseconds to be run with timemanager.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Since excel is not the same as csv and date-time data has been always a challenge, you could paste a exerpt of your csv file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description I could not find anything wrong, so please allow me to post an example, which is working at millisecond intervals at my end.

1) My dummy dataset:

[image]

2) Time manager panel. I set the *Time frame size:* unit to `milliseconds`.

[image]

3) Clicking on `[Settings]` button, and then `[Add layer]` button to read the layer. As you see, time format is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`.

[image]

4) Click on `[Time display options]` button, which shows `Options` window. Again DateTime format is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`.

[image]

That's all. Nothing special but hopefully you can find something.